# Set the cronjob

Tags: cron

I want to set a cronjob to execute after every 10 minutes from morning 1000 hours to evening 1730 hours. Is it possible to set this in the crontab file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this make me wish there was an option to close question because the OP has put in absolutely no effort to help themselves.

Answer (score 5):

You would need multiple entries for the job:

```
0,10.20,30,40,50 10-16 * * * myjob
0,10,20          17    * * * myjob
```

(Add "`,30`" to the second line if you want the end time to be inclusive.)

Comment: I have done that already. Is it possible to achieve this having a single cronjob entry ?

Comment: No; there have been several attempts to replace `cron` with something more flexible, but none ever caught on (the existing `cron` replacements all use the same time specification syntax).

Comment: If the OP really really wants one cronjob entry, he could add a check in his job to see if the time was in the correct range, and skip execution if not.